# Listing Duplicates in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
'{=IFERROR(INDEX(indirect("'"&$B$1&"'!E$8:E$105),MATCH(1,((COUNTIF(D2:D$2,indirect("'"&$B$1&"'!E$8:E$105))=0)*(COUNTIF(indirect("'"&$B$1&"'!E$8:E$105),indirect("'"&$B$1&"'!E$8:E$105))>=2)),0)),"")}'
```

I've tried using the above formula to list duplicate values in one sheet by searching whichever sheet name is in Cell B1. The above won't work, but I'm unsure as to why? Is it the syntax, or something else?

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of excel do you use?

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are a bit out of whack in the indirect functions

`indirect("'"&$B$1&"'!E$8:E$105)` should be `INDIRECT($B$1&"!E$8:E$105",1)`

It works for me after fixxing that, then deleting the dynamic range marks  i.e. `'{}'` , and finally changing the format of the cell to general

Comment: I've tried what you've suggested, and deleted the '{ }' marks, and also changed the format to general. But for some reason it gives me a circular reference error

Comment: Ok, go to the data tab. Click on Error Checking. And select Circular References to find it.

Comment: If you can't find it, then go to File Tab, click on Options. In the Formulas section check the box that says Enable Iterative Calculation. Just make sure to press calculate now every time you need it to calculate from then on.